# In plist files how to extract string text after unique key tag via xmlstarlet tool

Tags: xml, xpath, plist, xmlstarlet

I want to query plist XML files via [`xmlstartlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). I'm looking for the text of a `string` tag straight *after* a unique `key` tag. The XML file can look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>15B42</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>AppIcon</string>
    .
    .
    .
</dict>
</plist>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<othertag>
    <dict>
        <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
        <string>15B42</string>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
        <string>AppIcon</string>
        .
        .
        .
    </dict>
</othertag>
</plist>
```

In any case I am looking a way the string value after e.g. the key `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` (in this case `en`).

So the place in the hierarchy where the dict occurs is unknown (it can be `/plist/dict` or `/plist/another/dict` or somewhere else), but the key text is unique in the whole file.

I have tried

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//string/following::key[text()="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"]' myfile.plist
```

but I don't get any output. Is my XPath wrong or do I have to specify other parameters to `xmlstarlet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
//key[.='CFBundleDevelopmentRegion']/following-sibling::string[1]
```

The XPath will find `key` element, anywhere in the XML document, where the content equals `"CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"`, and then return the *nearest* following-sibling `string` element.

So the complete command-line with `xmlstarlet` looks like this:

```
xmlstarlet sel --net -t -v '//key[.="CFBundleShortVersionString"]/following-sibling::string[1]' myfile.plist
```